# javascript validation isn't working past validating email input

Tags: javascript

When I run the following script it will not validate past the email validation. I remove the email validation and it will continue. Any insights to what may be causing the problem?

```
vEmail = document.getElementById("xEmail").value;

// checks to see if email is formatted correctly
var atpos=vEmail.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=vEmail.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=z.length) {
    document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['email'].focus();
    alert("Please check your eMAIL ADDRESS. It doesn't appear correct.");
    return false;
    }

// *** check each field for SHIPPING values ***

vShipTo = document.getElementById("xShipTo").value;
     if (vShipTo=="") {         
     document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['ship_to'].focus(); 
     alert("No SHIP TO NAME entered");
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is z? (dotpos+2>=z.length)

Answer (score 0):

Unless z is defined elsewhere, I think the error stems from z not being defined.

```
 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=   (z.length)     ) {
```

This would cause it to fail as if the two conditions are not met, the program will encounter a reference error and stop running. If z is removed, the program continues toward the end.

Edit:

Also, this code is running within a function right?

Answer (score 0):

**Correct this(z is undefined here)**

```
if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2 >= z.length) {
```

to

```
if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2 >= vEmail.length) {
```

**Here is a working snippet**

```js
checkMail();
    
function checkMail(){
    vEmail = document.getElementById("xEmail").value;
      // checks to see if email is formatted correctly
     var atpos=vEmail.indexOf("@");
     var dotpos=vEmail.lastIndexOf(".");
    if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2 >= vEmail.length) {
         document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['email'].focus();
          alert("Please check your eMAIL ADDRESS. It doesn't appear correct.");
         return false;
 
    }
    //return false;need to set true
    }
```

```html
<body>
<form name="checkout_form" id="checkout_form" action="">
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" id="xEmail" name="email" value="@gmail.com">
  <br>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="return checkMail();"value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

Comment: I made the suggested corrections and it now works. Thanks for the sharp eyes.

Comment: Welcome.Click on big check button for accept the answer if it resolves you problem

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is probably the best way You can use to validate email

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}


vEmail = document.getElementById("xEmail").value;

// checks to see if email is formatted correctly
    if (!validateEmail(vEmail)) {
    document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['email'].focus();
    alert("Please check your eMAIL ADDRESS. It doesn't appear correct.");
    return false;
    }

// *** check each field for SHIPPING values ***

vShipTo = document.getElementById("xShipTo").value;
     if (vShipTo=="") {         
     document.forms['checkout_form'].elements['ship_to'].focus(); 
     alert("No SHIP TO NAME entered");
     return false;
    }
```